# Create a color palette image from a list of RGB color

Tags: python, image, numpy

I use [color thief](https://github.com/fengsp/color-thief-py) to extract a color palette from an image.

How to create an image of rgb value as a Palette?

```
from colorthief import ColorThief
color_thief = ColorThief('C:\Users\username\Desktop\index.jpg')
# get the dominant color
dominant_color = color_thief.get_color(quality=1)
print dominant_color
# build a color palette
palette = color_thief.get_palette(color_count=2)
print palette
```

Output:

```
(82, 129, 169)
[(82, 129, 169), (218, 223, 224), (147, 172, 193), (168, 197, 215), (117, 170, 212)]
```

The expected output is similar to http://www.color-hex.com/color-palette/895, i.e. a series of colored rectangles

Comment: What is your expected output? it has been lost

Comment: just an image containing color palette

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution using `imshow` from Matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

palette = [(82, 129, 169), (218, 223, 224), (147, 172, 193), (168, 197, 215), (117, 170, 212)]

palette = np.array(palette)[np.newaxis, :, :]

plt.imshow(palette)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

gives:

[image: result image]

Comment: actually, there is maybe a better tool than `matplotlib` if you want only an image of 3-5 colored squares...

Comment: The code shows only black color. Please tell me the better tool. No need to divide by 255. it solves my problem without dividing it by 255.

Comment: ok, it's not working for me without dividing by 255... maybe not same version of matplotlib

Comment: To save the output to a file, use `plt.savefig('palette.png')` between `imshow` and `show`